# How to call Hapi Plugins for certain routes?

Tags: plugins, hapi.js

Im using Hapi 12.1.

Trying to figure out how to call certain extension points only on certain routes.

For example for :
'/hello' 
I want to call three different extension points that work on the 'onRequest' step.

For:
'/goodbye'
I want to call a different extension point that works also on the 'onRequest'  but is a different operation and a 'onPreAuth' step.

For:
'/health'
Dont call any extension points, and just drop into the handler straight away..

I have tried various ways to create a plugin, define the routes, and extension points. But it seems the the extension points are global, and dont only operation on the plugin's scoped routes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have access to the path on your extension points, using `request.route.path`. With that, you can define what you want to run, depending on the path. Example:

```js
server.ext('onPreAuth', function (request, reply) {

    switch(request.route.path) {
        case '/test1':
        case '/test2':
            // Do something

            break;
        case '/test3':
            // Do something else

            break;
    }

    reply.continue();
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can also make it dependent on the route configuration:

```js
server.ext('onPreAuth', function (request, reply) {

    if(request.route.settings.plugins.runPreAuth) {
        // Do something

    }

    reply.continue();
});
```

Then, you just define in your route the configurations:

```js
server.route({
    method: 'get',
    path: '/test1',
    handler: function(request, reply) {

        reply({result: 'ok'});
    },
    config: {
        plugins: {
            runPreAuth: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont think the second method works anymore. "plugins" is not allowed. You can, however, use tags: `tags: ['something']` in the route definition and check it with `request.route.settings.tags`

Comment: @Yashua That is false... in [Route options](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options) documentation, you see:
`plugins - plugin-specific configuration. plugins is an object where each key is a plugin name and the value is the plugin configuration.`. I am using it with the latest version of hapijs.

Comment: `hapi@13.3.0` to be more precise.